# Symbol stripping of Objective-C code still leaves method names, etc. in binary

Tags: ios, objective-c, debug-symbols

I am trying to strip our iOS application binary of debug symbols to make it more difficult for hackers to modify the binary. I have tried both xcode's symbol stripping (enabling strip linked product and deployment postprocessing) and using "strip -S -x". Both do reduce the number of symbols, but running the binary through "strings" still returns loads of hits.

How do I remove them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Objective-C is a dynamic language.  Method calls are resolved at runtime based on selectors (effectively the method name as a string).  This is different from a language like C++ that binds method calls at compilation/link time.

Removing the method names (selectors) from the binary would make the application unusable.

Applications written in Objective-C are pretty much open books when it comes to their internals. Just look at tools like [`otool`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/otool.1.html), [`class-dump`](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/), [F-Script](http://www.fscript.org) or [DTrace](http://www.dtrace.org) to see how much is accessible and modifiable in a running Objective-C application.

However, there are linker flags (`P_LNOATTACH`) which stop DTrace connecting to the running application.  You can also call `ptrace` with the `PT_DENY_ATTACH` flag. iTunes is an example of an app that does this as Apple doesn't want you poking around inside their DRM.

There appears to be a previous post on Objective-C code obfuscation.  See [iPhone/iPad App Code Obfuscation - Is it Possible? Worth it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556849/iphone-ipad-app-code-obfuscation-is-it-possible-worth-it) for more details

Comment: iTunes, and other apps like the DVD player, have the `P_LNOATTACH` flag set which disables DTrace from within the kernel.

Comment: We set the PT_DENY_ATTACH flag to prevent debugging. Is there a tool for obfuscating method names? It sounds like that would solve the problem of making it harder to hack.

Comment: I just added PT_DENY_ATTACH to my answer and then saw your comment.  I suspect the only way you could obfuscate the method names would be to run a preprocessor over your code to mangle the method names before compilation.

Comment: I've updated my post with a link to a previous SO post about ObjC code obfuscation.  There are a few other hits searching for Objective-C code obfuscation

Comment: PT_DENY_ATTACH has been bypassed with a [generic method](https://github.com/gdbinit/onyx-the-black-cat)

Answer (score 1):

The objective-c runtime relies on those, it won't be possible to remove them. (The type 'SEL' is a uniqued char *)