# Remove debugger symbols from xCode 4.6

Tags: xcode, debug-symbols, stripping

I have an IOS app (ObjC and C++) I've just noticed that the output binary file contains debuger symbols - there are no variable names nor method names, but I can see class names.

All stripping settings are enabled, GenerateDebugSymbols is set to "no", but still class names are in the output file. Debugger also shows class names

Why does it happen? How can I remove ALL debug symbols? Are those symbols removed during/after upload to appstore?

Thanks,
Ed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symbol stripping of Objective C code still leaves method names, etc. in binary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171103/symbol-stripping-of-objective-c-code-still-leaves-method-names-etc-in-binary)

Comment: But why C++ class, without ObjC, marked as "C++ Source" are also in the output binary?