# How to obfuscate an iPhone app before being published into iTunes

Tags: objective-c

I am using cryptography concepts in my application. Some Encryption and decryption techniques and salt values are hard coded and IV values are using those techniques. Before I publish the app I need to obfuscate to my code. I am using XCode 6.2 version with updated OS. Please share with me techniques about how to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone/iPad App Code Obfuscation - Is it Possible? Worth it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556849/iphone-ipad-app-code-obfuscation-is-it-possible-worth-it)

Comment: Neither "decryption techniques " nor `iv` need to be kept secret, only the encryption key. Good security requires using proven methods and cryptographic primitives not secret methods.

Answer (score 1):

Neither "decryption techniques " nor `iv` need to be kept secret, only the encryption key. Good security requires using proven methods and cryptographic primitives not secret methods. Developer created cryptographic methods are usually insecure and lack peer review for flaws, the standard methods have been well researched and vetted for security flaws.

Shipping with the key embedded in the code is a problem, the key should be randomly generated (or in some similar process) at first-run and stored in the Keychain.